# Datastore 'Response too large error' since migrated to Python27

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just migrated my GAE/python app from M/S to HRD and then activated the new python27 runtime.
Now most of my datastore queries are failing with this error:

ResponseTooLargeError: The response from API call datastore_v3.RunQuery() was too large.

The same code is still running on older GAE app (M/S and python25) with no problems at all.
What is going on? Is this because of the new runtime or because of the HRD? Should I change my models/app to make request smaller?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to pinpoint a specific query that causes this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in the Python 2.7 runtime - if the result of a datastore query is >1MB then you will get this response.

It will be fixed in 1.6.1.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Do you know if there is an estimated date for 1.6.1 release?